# how to print from c side with Verilog or SystemVerilog

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-dpi

The question was how to log data from C model into terminal while running test. The answer is using vpi_print in C code instead of regular printf.

I have got some strikes for this question and have desided to make it clear.

The original version is right below

"While using DPI in SystemVerilog  I faced an issue to redirect stdout of C side into stdout of SystemVerilog to get all log writes in one place (In my case printf from C were displayed in terminal but not seemed in log file from EDA).

I know the 100% works solution it is export function from SV side and use it in C to print, but it does not seem to me clever.

I tried to use some sort of redirection using reopen functions to changed address stdout var points to (as far as I understand the stdout it is an address for program to write into), but eventually it redirects all logging into this stdout including SystemVerilog log.

What is a better way to keep all logs in one stream?

Maybe there is a way to get C know the IDE stdout?"

Comment: Which IDE? Which simulator are you using?

Comment: you can use `vpi_printf` instead.

Comment: I never used PLI but I will study the vpi_printf usage.

Comment: dpi replaces just a small part of vpi/pli, namely the way to call the functions from verilog and to pass params. The rest, like accessing simulation-time data structs and data,  and some extra stuff (including  vpi_printf) is still in  vpi domain.

Comment: I admitted vpi_printf was the best solution) and used this approach instead of calling SystemVerilog function from C side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer had been given by https://stackoverflow.com/users/1143850/serge

Use vpi_print function from C side. The vpi_print will put its output into the same stream as EDI does

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).